# How to manually define one to one key of legacy database in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.7

I'm trying to define models for a legacy database.
Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sysuser
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  login character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  passwd character varying(80) NOT NULL,
  created boolean DEFAULT false,
  deleted boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT sysuser_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);


CREATE TABLE userinfo
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT currval('sysuser_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(256),
  surname character varying(256)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

There is one to one relationship between those to tables using id column.

My goal is to get name and username by providing a login.
In SQL this would be:
    SELECT name, surname FROM sysuser JOIN userinfo USING(id) WHERE login = 'joe1'

How can I define my models to allow me to make this kind of query:

```
userlogin = 'joe1'
sysuser = Sysuser.objects.filter(deleted=False, created=True, login=userlogin).all()[:1]
#how to acheive this part?
print sysuser.userinfo.name #  Joe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do is define the `db_column` in the `Sysuser` model like this:

```
userinfo = models.ForeignKey(Userinfo, db_column='id')
```